# Как хранить логические (boolean) значения в MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Я храню в *tinyint(1)* - *0* или *1*. Проверку осуществляю:

```
WHERE is_public='1'
```

Конечно всё работает, но чувствую, что это неправильно. Вопрос - как это организовать правильно и более красиво?

Comment: всё правильно, в мускуле нет отдельного булевого типа

Comment: всё верно делаете

Comment: Только число со строкой не нужно сравнивать ;)

Comment: @Etki булев тип есть.... только толк от него такой же как от tinyint с его 1 и 0

Comment: Вы конечно можете взять int и уложить в него с помощью битовых операций до 32 признаков. Вопрос в том ради чего ? Будете экономить 1 мегабайт на диске на один признак в одном миллионе записей. Еще можно автоматом сделать, 0 хранить как NULL, а 1 как 1. тогда нулевые значения не будут занимать место. расход - 1 бит в заголовке записи на признак NULL но выбирать сложнее, is null не всегда удобно писать

Comment: Словами запишите `TRUE` и `FALSE`. Красиво и сразу ясно что к чему

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Очень часто хранят такие значения в `CHAR(1)` в виде 'Y' и 'N'. Из плюсов такого подхода можно отметить наглядность. Однако, экономии по сравнению с `TINYINT(1)` нет никакой, более того при использовании в таблице хотя бы одного столбца `VARCHAR`, все CHAR-столбцы автоматически рассматриваются как `VARCHAR`. VARCAHR-столбцы вынесены в отдельную область и обрабатываются медленнее `TINYINT`, во-вторых один байт будет использоваться для задания размера VARCHAR-значения и вместо одного байта будет использовано два. Поэтому `TINYINT(1)` - самый экономный и правильный вариант. Именно его часто используют широкоизвестные фреймворки, например, Ruby on Rails. Я бы на вашем месте не стал ничего менять.